# Масово обновить записи при добавлении кастомной таксономии?

Tags: wordpress, acf

Добавил кастомную таксономию "Метро" и через плагин Acf Field Group добавил это поле для выбора. Если указать станцию метро через плагин то нужно сохранить запись что бы станция добавилась в таксономию. Анкет очень много и по одному сохранять очень долго.

Можно ли автоматизировать сохранение записей?

Comment: Тебе помогут плагины для импорта контента. Однако с произвольными полями работают как правило их платные версии (вот напр https://www.wpallimport.com/advanced-custom-fields/). Если хочешь спам накодить импорт - изучай АПИ ВП.

Comment: Вы не поняли. Я заполнил кастомное поле, а что бы это значении добавилось в таксономию нужно сохранить запись. Может есть другое решение?. http://joxi.ru/J2bWMe5hGoEV3A

Comment: Какую-то вы ерунду городите)

Comment: В цикле пройдитесь и обновите  нужное поле: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/

Comment: Спасибо. Обновил 1 поле в цикле и все ок.